# Do I start out knowing all the cooking recipes in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm finding a lot of vegetables on my travels through Skyrim. Two in particular, the Carrot and the Potato, don't show up in any of the cooking recipes I started out with.

- Is there some method to learn new cooking recipes in-game, or are you stuck with what you know at the start?
- If not, is there any use for Carrots and Gourds(and other equally useless veggies) other than selling them en masse for 0 gold? (Even the NPCs think they're worthless!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get all the possible cooking recipes from the start: it just depends on what ingredients you have on hand. When you visit a cooking pot, you'll see all the available recipes, and when you have the right ingredients, the recipes will enable.

The stews and soup that you can make with cooking sell for a few gold and have some basic perks, but are not nearly as good as potions. In terms of what you can make with carrots and potatoes, there's:

#### Beef stew

*carrots, garlic, raw beef, and salt pile*
Increases max stamina by 25, stamina regeneration for 12 minutes

#### Cabbage potato stew

*cabbage, leeks, potatoes, and salt pile*
Restores 10 health and stamina

#### Vegetable soup

*cabbage, leeks, potatoes, and tomatoes*
Health and stamina regeneration for 12 minutes

#### Venison stew

*leeks, potatoes, salt pile, and venison*
Restores 15 stamina, health and stamina regeneration for 12 minutes

If you scroll over the other recipes while using a cooking pot, the items you need to make them are listed under the item detail box.

Comment: At some point potato soup was added. Potato and salt pile for +10 health and +10 stamina. Easier than cabbage potato soup for the same effects.

Comment: Potato soup(Potato and salt pile) for +10 health and +10 stamina. Easier than cabbage potato soup for the same effects.I know this won't pertain to the asked about ingredients, but there are a few other really useful recipes besides just the ones that regen stamina for 12 minutes. There's Elsweyr Fondue(Eidar Cheese Wheel, Ale and Moon Sugar) that give an extra 100 magicka and buffs regen by 25% for 10 to 12 minutes(can't remember). Another is in Hearthfire. Garlic Bread(whole loaf of bread, garlic, butter) cures disease. The recipe makes 2 Garlic Bread and each one weighs 0.1 carry weight.

Answer (score 2):

Sell them to the farmer near whiterun for 2 gold a piece

Answer (score 2):

Many of the small settlements across Skyrim have farmers who are harvesting wheat, potatoes, leeks and cabbage. If you harvest these crops for them, you can sell them at a premium price that you won't be able to get from any shop keepers. These farmers will also buy any of those vegetables that you are already holding in your inventory as if you had harvested those crops for them as well.

This is a simple way to make a little extra money early in the game that won't require you to go dungeon-diving at a low level :)