# What is the point of cooking food?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The amount of health restored is quite low compared to the hassle of getting the ingredients.  Is cooking tied in any way to a skill so the health benefits become better later on?

Finally, is it possible to add poison to cooked food?

Comment: One of the benefits I see to food is the small benefits, such as a the bonuses to stamina/health regeneration that some foods give.

Comment: See http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Cooking . There is only one recipe (apple cabbage stew) that results in a gain in sell value.

Comment: I almost want to put this on the Cooking site.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is one worthwhile cooking/food item: [Elsweyr Fondue](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Elsweyr_Fondue) provides a massive Magicka boost with an absurdly long duration.

Other cooking items are primarily just low level health and stamina consumables and can easily be ignored unless you're serious about role playing. Other than that, it's just another crafting mechanic that DLC and modders can easily hook into, so we might see more useful stuff in the future.

Comment: Or a hardcore mode! *fingers crossed*

Comment: wow, that fondue provides quite a good benefit!

Comment: @RavenDreamer: I think you typo'd an extra 'e' before that exclamation point.

Comment: What does the recipe for Elsweyr Fondue consist of?  Can you learn other recipies or are they added by mixing ingredients, similar to alchemy?

Comment: [All recipes are known from the start.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35299/do-i-start-out-knowing-all-the-cooking-recipes-in-skyrim) Elsweyr Fondue is made with Ale, Moon Sugar, and an Eidar Cheese Wheel.

Answer (score 20):

Quoting [Cooking is Overpowered](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWBDKY5WjrE) on YouTube:

> Cooking in Skyrim is not at all the worthless skill it is made out to be. The benefits of stamina regeneration are huge, while the value of fondue to a caster is more than you might realize.

Summary:

Apparently power attacks only require one point to be activated, which makes the long lasting Stamina Soups more useful than they appear to be. While under the effect of the soup, you can chain power attacks for twelve minutes.

Eslweyr Fondue increases your Magicka by 100 points, also for a duration of 720 seconds (12 minutes). This "saves you 10 levels worth of points that you do not have to invest in Magicka".

Well, that is if you can be bothered making the food in the first place. Personally I couldn't be bothered hunting for Eldar Cheese Wheels when I am already overwhelmed with Smithing, Enchanting and Alchemy. But when those skills are maxed this could be fun to play with :)

Comment: That's a great point about the stamina regen

Comment: I wonder how a _Regenerate Stamina_ enchanted jewelry would compare. I found a 40% faster stamina regeneration necklace around level 35. EDIT: [Cap seems to be 50%](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Generic_Magic_Apparel#Regenerate_Stamina). Perhaps higher values can be reached through the Alchemy/Enchanting loop, which would give the same effect as the Soup?

Comment: actually the cap for enchanting on it goes up to 37%, rather silly when the max you can find on an item goes up to 50%

Comment: Ack. Oh well :/  I've gotta do some real testing because I might be wearing this 40% necklace with little to no benefits.

Comment: [It seems Stamina Regeneration doesn't work during combat](http://www.gamespot.com/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/forum/stamina-regeneration-enchantment-not-working-in-combat-61204982). That's too bad I was hoping to combine this with Wind Walker perk.

Answer (score 6):

There is no cooking skill, however there are a few benefits of cooking over Alchemy:

- ingredients are more plentiful, and there are less options
- the ingredients by themselves will heal you (for a much smaller amount) even without cooking
- several foods (my favorite being Apple Cabbage Stew) restores both health and stamina still with the same simple ingredients
- the effects of food and ingredients don't have to be discovered, they are always known
- cooking can't fail and cause you to lose ingredients

Answer (score 3):

Food helps restore your stats like life, stamina, or magicka. Cooked food provides more substantial benefit compared to raw ingredients. For example vegetable soup helps restore health and stamina 1 point for 720 seconds.

Home cooked meal helps restore all three stats health, stamina and magicka for a certain amount of time.

Earlier in the game I was relying on home cooked meal, but as my character progressed I rely mostly on potions, spells or enchanted gear.

Answer (score 2):

There is no skill tied into cooking. It is helpful in the beginning when the player may not have many health potions as it upgrades food quality. At later levels, though, potions are very affordable and cooking is not required.

It is not possible to add poison to food.

Answer (score 2):

Beef stew, venison stew, vegetable soup (which is particularly handy as it requires only cabbage potato leek tomato, no salt or garlic). The the health benefit doesn't stack, but the stamina does. That's Huge for stuff you can make by picking up super common items while you're looting, stopping for 2 seconds at a cook pot... AND neither the ingredients or final products have any substantial weight. All benefits last 12 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Cooking is great when you're at low levels!  At the beginning of the game, you won't have many potions available and just going to your local alchemist and buying all their healing potions is too expensive when you start out.  Food items, though, can be picked up for free in every barrel or bag in every house, giving you a much cheaper alternative.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Is there any chance you can improve your answer a bit? The original asker was asking if by cooking you can get another benefit down the line related to skills. He also asked if it's possible to poison cooked food. If you are familiar with this game and know the answer please edit your post and you'll have my upvote =)

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of cooking that other questions haven't explicitly drawn out is precisely that it *isn't* tied to any skill.

The best way to gain access to a steady supply of specific potions is either alchemy or trade, and investing time in those activities necessitates gaining levels in their associated skills. If you'd like to access reliable healing effects whilst minimising the levels you gain in 'secondary' skills, cooking is one way to achieve that.