# Is there any actual use for food in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the point of cooking food?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36555/what-is-the-point-of-cooking-food)

My current character has been in this world for 128 days, and eaten *twice*.

Is there any actual use for food in this game, other than for roleplaying value, crafting xp, (is there even an associated skill?) or profit?

EDIT:  To clarify, by "eaten twice", I mean *has eaten* twice.  Although he's probably *been eaten* a bit more than that.