# Will eating raw food have a negative effect?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Just getting started with this Skyrim thing.  I have some raw meat items which categorize as food, but I don't see an obvious way to cook them (I assume that will come later).  If I eat them raw is there a chance I'll get poisoned or have some other negative side effect?

I looked at [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36555/what-is-the-point-of-cooking-food), but it didn't seem to mention any raw food effects, and I couldn't find other answers that mention raw food.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can consume raw food all you like.  Even raw clams and raw meat will never cause ill effects.  You can drop it on the floor, stand on top of it, drag it through the mud, leave it in a box in your house for weeks, and then chow down as if it was fresh.

It's not really worth much as far as restoring your stats, though.  Even cooked, most foods aren't worth the effort.  Sink some time into learning a few basic alchemy recipes for restore health and you'll be far better off.

Comment: If I decide to eat it, I'll be sure to add some *gravel breadcrumbs* as you suggest.

Comment: I can leave it in a box, but can I eat it with a fox?

Answer (score 2):

As with all items that may be consumed, your player can learn what effects come from each items. whether it be a increase in health, or a resist to fire. All consumables have up to four **unknowns**. By eating it, you find out one of them.